# how I can slow grind down the line in android?

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I mean I want to drawline but slowly.
I write this code to draw line in ondraw method.

```
.
.
.
.
caneta.setARGB(255, 255, 0,0);caneta.setStrokeWidth(10); 
canvas.drawLine(0, ys * 1/2, this.getWidth(), ys * 1/2, caneta);
.
.
.
```

how I did it slowly?

Comment: You need some sort of background thread to do that. You won't see anything (besides the ANR popup) if you do it slowly inside `onDraw` since the screen only updates after `onDraw` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nearly like a gameloop works:

-invalidate your canvas ever X milliseconds (using a loop and Thread.sleep())

-increment your X/Y coords after every loop

-handle the new coords in onDraw() again

Example:

```
private int x1, x2;
    private int y1, y2;
    private View v;

    public void start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 250; i++)
        {
             v.invalidate();

             x2 += 1;

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

in your existing view class, where you already have your onDraw method

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
        //draw your line here using your X and Y member
                canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, caneta);
        }
```

Comment: when ı use thread.sleep it do not draw . İ wait it for the end  and it draw immediately at the end of the loop

Comment: dont forget to invalite your canvas and to draw over and over again! It's like: "loop, draw, new coords, invalidate, sleep... loop again, draw again, new coords, invalidate again, sleep again..."...

Comment: can you give some code example pls.I really do not understand :( . how do ı this

Comment: thanks for answering but I dont have view v  I have game2 class that extends view. game2.invalidate do not work

Comment: I write this.invalidate(); it works but it do not draw slowly again

Comment: do some console output in your console! How often is your "onDraw()" method called? (should be called after every invalidate() ) furthermore, android view HAS invalidate! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

In every `onDraw` method call, draw a portion of the line incrementally, depending on the speed required. For example, if you want a slow drawing, increase the size by say 5 pixels in every call till the full line is reached.

```
private float linePercent = 0;
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){

    float lineX = this.getWidth() * linePercent;
    canvas.drawLine(0, ys * 1/2, lineX, ys * 1/2, caneta);
    linePercent += 0.05f;
    if(linePercent >= 1){
        linePercent = 0;
    }
}
```

And in a background thread, schedule an `invalidate` on your view.

Comment: can you try a smaller increment - say 1 pixel or even less (using a float value)?

Comment: I try it for(0,1000,++)drawline(..); but it draw immediately

Comment: ı try this . when I touch the screen it draw  a little . When ı touch screen again it draw a little. I do not want this.I want to for ex : when i touch screen or press button i want to see draw line slowly and ı want see this . thanks